# How would I change the JFrame background image while project is running

Tags: java, swing, background, jpanel

I set my background with

```
static JLabel board = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/rsz_board.png"));
frame.setContentPane(board);
```

And I tried to change the background with a button by doing this:

```
static JLabel board2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/board.png"));
JButton button2 = new JButton("Test");
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        frame.setContentPane(board2);
    }
});
```

When I click the button, nothing will happen. If I click the button and then resize the window by dragging it with my cursor, the background will change but all my buttons will disappear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post a [mcve] for more comprehensive help. One main problem is that your JLabel is covering up anything added previously to the JFrame's contentPane. You should draw in a JPanel's paintComponent method, and use that as your main JPanel that you add components to. This is well discussed in many similar questions on this site, and you would do well to search for similar questions to see how to do this in a best practice fashion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `revalidate()` and `repaint()` after changing the background.

try this:

```
static JLabel board2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/board.png"));
JButton button2 = new JButton("Test");
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        frame.setContentPane(board2);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
});
```

Comment: Cool, that solved the issue of the background (I tried repaint(); and it didn't work, didn't try it with revalidate();... thanks for that), but all the other buttons on my screen still disappear.

Comment: @baminian You add the label as the content pane, if you change the content pane you have to add it's child component again, like the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better way to do what you want: create a JPanel that draws the image in the background within its paintComponent method, that has its own layout manager which helps allow you to add components to the JPanel in any fashion you deem appropriate. You would give this class an Image field, and then within the paintComponent method, draw whatever image is being referenced by that field. Or if you want to swap a collection of images, give it an `ArrayList<Image>` field (below called images), and then draw the current image that is referenced by an index to that list (in my code below called imageIndex).

Comments on your code:

- You're using static variables for some Swing components, and that suggests that you should re-think your design. Only declare static that which makes sense being static, and Swing GUI components are almost never in that category.
- When you use a JLabel as you're using it, the label always sizes to the image and the text it holds (if any) which is OK for some applications, but dangerous for others. A JPanel will set its preferred size to that of the components it holds depending on the layout. That all changes of course if you explicitly change its `getPreferredSize()` method as I have done.

For example, compile and run the complete program code below:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChangeBackground extends JPanel {
    public static final String ROOT_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/";
    public static final String[] IMG_PATHS = {
        "0/01/Sundomecloseup.JPG/640px-Sundomecloseup.JPG",
        "3/31/Hanalei,_Kauai_HI.JPG/640px-Hanalei,_Kauai_HI.JPG",
        "a/a3/Castle_of_Vajdahunyad.jpg/640px-Castle_of_Vajdahunyad.jpg",
        "d/d6/HeratFridayMosque.jpg/640px-HeratFridayMosque.jpg",
        "1/16/Hebridean_ram.jpg/640px-Hebridean_ram.jpg",
        "1/11/Ouagadougou_Maison_du_peuple.jpg/640px-Ouagadougou_Maison_du_peuple.jpg",
        "9/96/Menger-Schwamm-einfarbig.jpg/640px-Menger-Schwamm-einfarbig.jpg",
        "4/4f/Olympias.1.JPG/640px-Olympias.1.JPG",
        "1/18/Uscapitolindaylight.jpg/640px-Uscapitolindaylight.jpg",
        "9/9a/Below_Golden_Gate_Bridge.jpeg/640px-Below_Golden_Gate_Bridge.jpeg",
        "2/29/Eiffel_Tower_(2962488972).jpg/640px-Eiffel_Tower_(2962488972).jpg",
        "8/8f/Notre-Dame_Cathedral_Basilica.jpg/640px-Notre-Dame_Cathedral_Basilica.jpg"
        };
    private static final int PREF_W = 640;
    private static final int PREF_H = 480;
    private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
    private int imageIndex = 0;

    public ChangeBackground(List<Image> images) {
        this.images = images;

        add(new JButton(new NextImageAction("Next Image")));
    }

    public void nextImage() {
        imageIndex++;
        imageIndex %= images.size();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class NextImageAction extends AbstractAction {
        public NextImageAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            nextImage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(images.get(imageIndex), 0, 0, this);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui(final List<Image> images) {
        ChangeBackground mainPanel = new ChangeBackground(images);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ChangeBackground");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Image> imgs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String imagePath : IMG_PATHS) {
            imagePath = ROOT_PATH + imagePath;
            try {
                URL imgUrl = new URL(imagePath);
                imgs.add(ImageIO.read(imgUrl));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui(imgs));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I click the button and then resize the window by dragging it with my cursor, the background will change but all my buttons will disappear

That is because all the buttons have been added to the "board" component not the "board2" component.

> I tried to change the background with a button by doing this:

Don't change the label that is being used as the content pane. Instead change the Icon of the label:

```
//frame.setContentPane(board2);
board.setIcon( new ImageIcon("img/board.png") );
```